# Display color of particles

Tags: particles, color

I am trying out Particles systems within Blender 2.79. When I have an object emitting particles I can easily see them but when adding a second force and playing with the scene the particles are black on my screen on a dark gray background making it hard to see. I am not looking to render the particles a different color but be able to display them on the screen a different color than black, any help even a link to someone else answering this question would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into the [display](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/emitter/display.html) options in your particle system. This can help diagnose issues as well as get a better idea of the behavior of your emitter.

Here is an example of color by velocity.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand if you create particle emitter it choses a default material in my case it was black so it was hard to see. so I created a new material for the object and now I can see it much better.